# Background on the Stone-von Neumann theorem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, hilbert, von-neumann

I'm a mathematician.
I'm required to give a lecture on the [Stone-von Neumann theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93von_Neumann_theorem). I already have all the mathematical details figured out, but I wish to make the lecture more interesting by giving the physical connection to the theorem.

Problem is, I don't recall much of the quantum physics course I took as an electrical engineering student 10 years ago. Can you please give me a fair background on the theorem, in simple words, I can present as an intro to the mathematical details (Historical anecdotes, the relation to the wave function etc.)?

Comment: See [Rosenberg, A Selective History of the Stone-von Neumann Theorem](https://www.math.umd.edu/~jmr/StoneVNart.pdf).

Comment: Thanks. I've encountered this document however it contains physical & mathematical notions I'm not familiar with. I was looking for something more concise.

Comment: You can try the introduction to [Summers' chapter On the Stone — von Neumann Uniqueness Theorem and Its Ramifications](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-94-017-2012-0_9), it is shorter, but I doubt you'll find something without notions you are not familiar with. Just ignore them as much as you can (or look up), and see if you can make enough of the rest.

Comment: Great reference! Thanks.